# ORACLE update with returning OLD and NEW values

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql, plsql, oracle12c

Is there equivalent to this T-SQL query in PL/SQL (Oracle 12c)?

`UPDATE A SET A.columnA = 10 WHERE A.columnB < 30 OUTPUT INSERTED.*, DELETED.*`

The query updates table A and at the same time returns the status of the record before the update and after the update.

Trigger is not a solution for me as well as SELECT records before and SELECT records after updating.

Answer (score 9):

Not a direct one, but using [`RETURNING INTO`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm) you will be able to achieve the same effect:

```
CREATE TABLE A(columnA VARCHAR2(10), columnB INT);
INSERT INTO A(columnA, columnB) VALUES ('Test', 10);
INSERT INTO A(columnA, columnB) VALUES ('Row 2', 20);
CREATE TABLE audit_table(col_new VARCHAR2(10),col_old VARCHAR2(10));

DECLARE
   TYPE rec IS RECORD (actual A.columnA%TYPE, old A.columnA%TYPE);
   TYPE col_a_t IS TABLE OF rec;
   v_a col_a_t;
BEGIN
  UPDATE (SELECT A.*, (SELECT A.columnA FROM dual) AS old_columnA FROM A)
  SET columnA = 'XYZ'
  WHERE columnB < 30
  RETURNING columnA, old_columnA BULK COLLECT INTO v_a;
  COMMIT;

  -- printing for debug
  FOR i IN v_a.first .. v_a.last LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line('Old =>' || v_a(i).old || ' new => ' || v_a(i).actual);
  END LOOP;

  -- additional
  FORALL i IN v_a.first .. v_a.last
    INSERT INTO audit_table VALUES v_a(i);
  COMMIT;
END;
/

SELECT * FROM A;
SELECT * FROM audit_table;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e27b90d47ebfc219f14ddf2ab6d07bb1)**

---

<sup>Idea taken from: [Returning Old value during update](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/177753/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can't return old and new values in an update statement in Oracle 12c, but they are introduced in Oracle Database 23c where you can return the old and new values of the columns from the rows touched by the UPDATE statement. Your code will be like this:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE OLD_columnA_T IS TABLE OF A.columnA%TYPE;
  TYPE NEW_columnA_T IS TABLE OF A.columnA%TYPE;

  OLD_columnA OLD_columnA_T;
  NEW_columnA NEW_columnA_T;
BEGIN
  UPDATE A
     SET A.columnA = 10
   WHERE A.columnB < 30
  RETURNING OLD columnA, NEW columnA 
  BULK COLLECT INTO OLD_columnA, NEW_columnA;

  FOR I IN 1 .. OLD_columnA.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Old.columnA = ' || OLD_columnA(I));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('New.columnA = ' || NEW_columnA(I));
  END LOOP;

END;
```

For more details, please check the following links:

[RETURNING INTO Clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/lnpls/RETURNING-INTO-clause.html#GUID-38F735B9-1100-45AF-AE71-18FB74A899BE)

[DML RETURNING Clause Enhancements in Oracle Database 23c](https://oracle-base.com/articles/23c/dml-returning-clause-enhancements-23c)