# How to check previous value after update in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I updated a column in the oracle table on Jan 1 2022 and committed, how to check which value is present before the update in that particular column.

Is there any possibility to view which value is there in that column on Dec 31, 2021.

Thanks

```
select salary from emp where id = 1111;
```

Comment: You should just keep the original record around as a backup.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51511956/how-to-get-latest-updated-record-in-oracle/51512816#51512816

Comment: If you run a database in `archivelog` mode and supplemental logging is enabled, then you may use [`flashback_query_clause`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6)  of `select` statement to see previous state of the data. If you need this value for processing after an update, then you may use `returning` clause of `update` statement with a trick. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46927268/oracle-update-with-returning-old-and-new-values.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you cannot. Once you update a table then the previous value is gone.

However:

- If you have a history/logging table that you populate whenever you update the main table (typically via a trigger or a procedure) then you can retrieve the historic value from that table; however, you would have had to create the history table and the procedure/trigger beforehand.
- If you have flashback enabled on the database/tablespace/table and the flashback retention period is long enough then you can use:

  ```sql
  SELECT salary
  FROM   emp AS OF TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP '2021-12-31 23:59:59.999999999'
  WHERE  id = 1111
  ```

  If you did not enable flashback before the change or the flashback retention period is shorter than required then that will not work.
- Assuming that you backup your database (please say you backup your database), you can restore the database to the most recent back-up from before the date in question and then you can query the table from that back-up date.